# How to create a when expression in spark with loops

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I have a requirement to a create a column based on multiple ***when*** statements.

```
df.withColumn("new colume",when(col("col1").isin("list of item1"),"item1")
                           .when(col("col1").isin("list of item2"),"item2")
                           ....)
```

Is there anyway I can create a chain of ***when*** condition using a loop ? My plan is put input and output of ***when*** in a map like

```
Map("item1" -> "list of item1","item2" -> "list of item2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `when` / `otherwise` with `foldLeft`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val conditions = Map(
  "item1" -> Seq("foo", "bar"), "item2" -> Seq("foobar")
)

conditions.foldLeft(lit(null)){
  case (acc, (v, ls)) => when(col("col1").isin(ls: _*), v).otherwise(acc)  
}
```

which will create an nested `CASE WHEN` expression of form:

```sql
CASE WHEN (col1 IN (foobar)) THEN item2 
     ELSE CASE WHEN (col1 IN (foo, bar)) THEN item1 
          ELSE NULL 
     END 
END
```

You can replace `lit(null)` with another value, that you want to use as a base outcome (if no value matches).

You can also generate

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN (col1 IN (foo, bar)) THEN item1 
  WHEN (col1 IN (foobar)) THEN item2 
END
```

using a recursive function like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def mergeConditions(conditions: Map[String, Seq[String]], c: Column) = {
  def mergeConditionsR(conditions: Seq[(String, Seq[String])], acc: Column): Column = conditions match {
    case (v, ls) :: t => mergeConditionsR(t, acc.when(c.isin(ls: _*), v))
    case Nil          => acc
  }

  conditions.toList match {
    case (v, ls) :: t => mergeConditionsR(t, when(c.isin(ls: _*), v))
    case Nil          => lit(null)
  }
}

mergeConditions(conditions, col("col1"))
```

but it shouldn't make much difference.

With simple is in it is of course possible to skip `when` completely:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

val conditionsCol = typedLit(conditions.flatMap {
  case (k, vs) => vs.map { v => (v, k) } 
}.toMap)

df.withColumn("value", conditionsCol($"col1"))
```

or by converting `conditions` to a `DataFrame` and joining.

```
conditions.toSeq.toDF("value", "col1")
  .withColumn("col1", explode($"col1"))
  .join(df, Seq("col1"), "rightouter")
```